# i want to add user activity to database in django

Tags: django, django-models

i want to add login and logout time of every user to the data base

in my model i dont know how to create it

model.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES,default='UTC')
    login_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    logout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every time a user login or logout the current activity is stored

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def dash_board(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if User.objects.filter(username=request.POST['username'], 
            password=request.POST['password']).exists():
            global user
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'], 
            password=request.POST['password'])


            act = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
            act.login_time = datetime.now()
            act.save()
            return render(request, 'dash.html', {'user': user, })

        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html')


@csrf_exempt
def logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        act = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
        act.logout_time=datetime.now()
        act.save()
        return render(request,'index.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Error While LogOut..!!</h1>")
```

Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added default value of datetime.now() which will set the values of those columns to the time when migration is run. That's why by default instead of current time you will always have that fixed value.

Try it like this

```
from django.utils import timezone

login_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
logout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This will update the default value with current time

Comment: activity =models.DateTimeField(login_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()),logout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()))  ,   is this above model is possible ...?

Comment: just remove the () from the now. After that, it will pick the current time with every request rather than the fixed time

Answer (score 1):

You don't create id it's exist by default by id=pk
The same in username and password  django when you check user username  or user.password it's  exist in django

```
          class User(models.Model):
                 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
                 login_time = 
                 models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
                 logout_time = 
                 models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
                 def __str__(self):
                     return self.name
```